# Объединить [инструменты] и [инструменты-разработчика]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

На ruSO мы имеем две метки: [инструменты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b) и [инструменты-разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0). По первой 7 вопросов, по второй — 16.

Предлагаю их объединить, сделав [инструменты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b) главной, поскольку любые инструменты не-разработчика — оффтоп.

Comment: [tag:google-chrome-devtools], хотя есть же не только хром...

Comment: Я бы обе метки удалил, как недостаточно конкретные. Ну или давайте их как-то конкретизируем .. ?

Answer (score 1):

### Удалить эти метки воообще

Дело в том, что данные метки очень похожи на метаметки, так как их можно применить почти к любом вопросу, так как всё, что хоть как-то связано с программированием создано каким-то инструментом разработки. Поэтому предлагаю их вовсе удалить.

Также они никакой информативности и специфики не добавляют ни к одному вопросу, что свидетельствует о том, что они не нужны. То есть если удалить их с любого вопроса, то он никак не пострадает.

Answer (score 0):

### *Инструменты разработчика* оставить, *инструменты* удалить

Ничего объединять не надо.

Соглашусь с тем, что [инструменты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b) является метаметкой.

Однако [инструменты-разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) — это компонент Google Chrome, и вопросы с данной меткой относятся исключительно к нему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Примечание: эти инструменты доступны через горячую клавишу <kbd>F12</kbd>.*

Comment: Неправда,  инструменты разработчика — это, **как минимум**, не только в Google Chrome, но и в любом другом браузере. Также, посмотрите вопросы по метке [tag:инструменты-разработчика], там и Java, и C++. Неужели любую среду разработки нельзя назвать инструментами разработчика?

Comment: Под хром уже есть метка [tag:google-chrome-devtools]

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight насколько они отличаются от инструментов разработчика в других браузерах?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Не знаю. На EN SO существуют разные метки [google-chrome-devtools], [firefox-developer-tools] и т.п., если это что-то значит.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Крайне похожи на инструменты в других браузерах и также называются. Иногда под инструментами разработчика могут понимать не только браузерные компоненты.